# If $X \simeq S^n$, then $X- \mathring{D^n} \simeq S^n - \mathring{D^n}$ for an $n$-manifold $X$

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, homotopy-theory, low-dimensional-topology

I am trying to understand (and prove) why the following should be true: let $X$ be an $n$-dimensional closed manifold homotopy equivalent to $S^n$. If $D^n \subseteq X$ is an embedded disc, I would like to see why $X- \mathring{D^n}$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^n- \mathring{D^n}$.

*Context.* This step is needed in the proof of the generalised Poincaré conjecture using Smale's h-cobordism theorem. Removing two open discs yields an homotopy equivalence with $S^{n-1} \times I$ and one can apply the h-cobordism theorem. In the question I only removed one disc for simplicity.

Comment: Just prove vanishing of homotopy groups: use SVK theorem for $\pi_1$, then for $\pi_k, k\ge 2$ use homology plus Hurewicz theorem.

Comment: Technically, you would need to know that the punctured manifold is homotopy equivalent to a CW complex. I think this is always the case, but it is nontrivial.

Comment: I assume that if I wanted to show that  $X- (\mathring{D_1^n} \cup \mathring{D_2^n} ) \simeq S^n - (\mathring{D_1^n} \cup \mathring{D_2^n} )  \simeq S^{n-1} \times I$ then you are proposing I should try to see that removing two discs yields a space with the same homotopy groups as $S^{n-1}$. Is this right?